# One Hyperlink In Many Different Locations

Tags: asp.net, html, master-pages, hyperlink, literals

I'd like to implement a hyperlink in many locations on my website, however I just want to have it defined once not several times over.  What is the best way to achieve this?

I started down the road of listing it in the  node of web.config but I was only able to get that to list as a literal and wasn't successful in having it end up as a hyperlink.

I don't know much about master pages, but what I do know about them seems to me that they aren't the answer for this task because they wouldn't allow for that hyperlink to be located on some pages and not others and in different locations on some pages than others.

Help please! :)

I'm working in ASP.net VB.net

Answer (score 0):

Put a `HyperLink` control on each page where you want it.

e.g. `<asp:HyperLink runat="server" id="LogInLink">Login</asp:HyperLink>`

Then either set the `NavigateUrl` property on the hyperlink in code-behind, e.g. `this.LogInLink.NavigateUrl = Global.MySpecialUrl;` or use `<%=Global.MySpecialUrl%>` notation to reference the value you want from your code in the `NavigateUrl` in the markup.

[Sorry, that's C# code]

Comment: Ok, I was hoping that there would be a way to do with without code behind.  But, that looks understandable...  How about the text related to the hyperlink, how would you declare that only in one place as well?

Comment: Well you *can* set that in code behind too, or use the <%= technique, or your could look into using resource files e.g. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fw69ke6f(VS.80).aspx

Comment: What would the <%= technique look like for something like this?  Btw, thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custom control that inherits from HyperLink. This method will not require to use code-behind on individual pages but you will need to create a new class and modify your web.config file. Alter the namespaces as needed.

**SpecialLink.vb**

```
Namespace YourWebSite.Controls
 Public Class SpecialLink
  Inherits HyperLink

  Public Sub New()
   NavigateUrl = "~/SpecialLinkUri.aspx"
   Text = "Special Link Text"
  End Sub
 End Class
End Namespace
```

**web.config** (add this to the system.web node)
*This allows you to use this control on any page/master page/user control throughout your site*

```
<pages>
  <controls>
   <add namespace="YourWebSite.Controls" tagPrefix="YourWebSite"/>
  </controls>
</pages>
```

**Using it on your page**

```
<p>This is some text, here's the link: <YourWebSite:SpecialLink></YourWebSite:SpecialLink></p>
<p>This is some text, <YourWebSite:SpecialLink>here's the link</YourWebSite:SpecialLink>.</p>
```